# Format MS Access Datetime using ODBC query

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access, datetime, format

I need to format datetime that comes from MS Access to "m-d-yyyy" using odbc in C#.net( desktop app).
"Select Format([Date],'M-d-yyyy') from table" does not work.

Thanks,
Kanaya

Comment: What do you mean "does not work"? Format will produce a date formatted in the order specified, but it will be text, not datetime. The order of day, month and year is normally controlled by the locale settings of the computer you are working on, if you want a different order it is generally a display issue, not a data issue.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Select convert(char, [Date], 101)
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be over simplifying this but:

```
m-d-yyyy
```

won't work as Days/Months can have up to two digits, what you need is:

```
mm-dd-yyyy
```

Comment: Matt, using m-d just means that the zero is optional, so 1/12 will be returned as 1-12, with mm-dd it would be returned as 01-12